# Trying to listen to on host 127.0.0.1 but with differnt ports

Tags: node.js, port, hostname, ngrok

i have implemented a broid API config to my nodeJs app
to listen to 2 different ports with the same host name

hosted on ngrok
Host : 127.0.0.1
port for facebook : 3000
port for viber : 5000

but it makes no differences everything tries to get processed through the facebook endpoint as it doesn't differentiate   between the two ports

any workarounds ?

```
    //initialize all platforms via broid
const clients = {

   messenger: new BroidMessenger({token: FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN ,
   tokenSecret:VERIFY_TOKEN ,
     http: {
     host: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 3000
   }}),  

 viber : new BroidViber({ 
  username: 'broidbotversiontwo',
  token: "TOKEN",
  webhookURL: "https://64065d3a.ngrok.io",
  http: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 5000
  }
})
```

Comment: https://github.com/broidHQ/integrations

git for BROID for more info

Comment: One process can only bind to one port at a time.

Comment: but broid is supposed to be able to connect to multiple platforms at the same time